# Translate Hash routine from Java to Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, hash

I have the following Java routine that I need to translate to Delphi. I know how to do the Base64 encoding but I am not sure what the Delphi equivalent for MessageDigest is. How would I write this method in Delphi?

```
    private String getHashCode(String s) {
        String outputHash;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1"); // SHA-256
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            outputHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            outputHash = "";
        }
        return outputHash;
    }
```

Comment: Hashing is about bytes, not texts. Make sure your Delphi `String` really has an UTF-8 encoding, otherwise hash sums will differ.

Comment: function TfrmMain.GetXMLHashCode(pString: string): string;
var
  SHA1: TIdHashSHA1;
  Hash: TidBytes;
begin
  SHA1 := TIdHashSHA1.Create;
  try
    try
      Hash := SHA1.HashString(pString);
      Result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(Hash);
    except on E: Exception do
      Result := '';
    end;
  finally
    SHA1.Free;
  end;
end;